# How to render Vue page on direct visit?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vue I have a page that a user sees following a certain user flow.
Lets say this page is called `mysite.com/listing/2031`.

When I try to visit this page directly, it will throw a 404. This is because its not a static content and the server doesn't know how to serve it directly without javascript.

Since `mysite.com/listing/2031` is a public view I need this to be available for direct visit. Many people suggest redirecting to index.html on the webserver level but in my case I need to somehow let Vue know to re-render that page.

How should I approach this case?

Thanks!

Comment: You can disable `history` mode in your router config to allow the *hash mode*. If you do not want to see `#` in your url, you need to configure your server to always serve the same `index.html` page. Look at [the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) for examples.

Comment: Without *history* mode I will now have this: history.pushState API to achieve URL navigation without a page reload? Is there another way to achieve this? In development mode the pages load on direct visit with history mode as well.

Comment: You could use this https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages. The example is using React but it works for Vue as well.

Comment: @KasparTr, in Vue.js, you should't use `history.pushState` directly. You should use [`vue-router`](https://router.vuejs.org/) instead. It supports [programmatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) and will allow you to navigate without refreshing the page (with or without "`#`"). To remove the `#`, you need to [configure your prod web server](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) (Apache, nginx, IIS...). The dev nodejs server is already preconfigured to redirect everything to `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks @thibautg putting the mode to 'hash' didn't break my design and pages now load directly. The nginx configuration of ''try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;" didn't help with that hashtags in the URL though, neither does it actually redirect not found pages to index.html?

Comment: @KasparTr I don't know how it works with nginx, but with Apache you need to activate `mod_rewrite` and add the rewrite rule in the `httpd.conf` (or vhost conf) or in a `.htaccess` file in your app's directory.